# Updating ASUS X550ze BIOS without battery

Tags: bios, asus-laptop

I have a **Asus x550ze** laptop. This laptop shows me a `blue screen` and after many searches I found that I must update the `BIOS`  to solve this problem.  However, my laptop doesn't have a battery and I always use AC Power.

I have tested many ways and searched many sites but I cannot find a solution for **update bios without battery**.

**winflash.exe** didn't help me because this application shows me an error for **battery** and when I run it from `cmd` by using `/f` or `/forceit`  it show me another error like "file can not find".

I downloaded the **afudos** for updating bios from `MS - Dos` But it not work and show me error like this : `file creating error` or `file not found`.

Does that mean that if anybody loses his laptop battery one can't use his laptop anymore?

Update :

I need update bios for solve bluescreen that shows a error for driver of graphic and i installed latest driver from asus site but i find out this problem comes from bios and i must update it

Comment: When does your laptop shows you blue screen: straight from the boot or after some time during the usage of the machine? Have you tried looking for the official BIOS updates on the Asus website https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/X550ZE/HelpDesk_Download/?

Comment: A battery is REQUIRED to update the BIOS on most notebooks, what don't you understand about that? In most notebooks you cannot override this in any way (and I cannot find a way for newer Asus devices)... Buy a battery, they are like $14 on Amazon for the X550. Also remember that "newer" devices like this don't have plain old BIOS like the old days, they use a UEFI firmware which although it does many of the same things it *is* different, I wouldn't be fooling with WinFlash or other 3rd party tools unless your ready to deal with a bricked laptop.

Comment: @acejavelin i can't Buy new battery because my laptop can't detect the battery because i fixed my mainboard problems by cutting the battery cable from the mainborad

Comment: @alljamin i'm saying about flash bios without battery . are you sure read my question ? i could find bios files from asus and it was't my problem

Comment: @AbbasNikzad Honestly, then your out of luck... If the system can't detect a battery then you can't update the bios.

Comment: @acejavelin i saw one answer about this problem in the internet that it can by using afudos and dos oprating system . i installed free dos in my usb flash memory and i copied afudos.exe with bios file inside flash memory but afudos not work and can't detect the bios file .

Comment: There must be a way because if can't update bios without battery i can't use my laptop anymore and i must throw it out from window :)

Comment: Those tools like AsusFlashUtility for DOS (afudos) are all for the older PC's and motherboards with real "BIOS" not UEFI firmware, they haven't been used in over 6 years and do not work on modern machines.

Comment: Please update your question with all the information you've mentioned in your comments. You left my question unanswered, so I repeat them again: When does your laptop shows you blue screen: straight from the boot or after some time during the usage of the machine? The reason why I ask this is to ensure that it is a BIOS problem not something else.

Comment: @alljamin it show bluescreen after boot and sometimes after welcome screen and its about graphic driver but i searched and asket about this error and the only way for solve this blue screen is updating bios

Comment: Have you tried using another HDD? If you computers boots and blue screen appears after the boot it has (most probably) nothing to do with BIOS.

Comment: @alljamin i'm using SSD and i tried it by another HDD in past . i tested all ways but this issue is from BIOS or only Graphic Driver . I worked on Graphic side more and I understood its a bios problem after laptop fixing .

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the new bios (for me X75A1AS.412) and copy it on USB key (FAT32).
2. Start and enter bios, then in bios menu : "Advanced" -> "Start Easy Flash"
3. When the system will display that you can not update the bios because there is no battery, on your keyboard you enter "risky"

[upgrade BIOS on Asus without EasyFlash and WinFlash](https://superuser.com/questions/1311384)